# Roslyn - Access all used Types within a MethodSymbol

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, roslyn

i currently have a IMethodSymbol in access, and now i want to get all used types within this Method. That means

- The ITypeSymbol of declared, local variables
- The ITypeSymbol of methodcalls within the given Methodsymbol, which are returing a Type (not System.Void).
- The ITypeSymbol of all parameters in any methodcall within this method.

The question would be, if roslyn is supporting this which a gracefull API, or if i have to iterate over the syntaxtree and search the information on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to accomplish with a `CSharpSyntaxWalker` visiting the method body where you collect the symbols from variable declarations and invocation expressions. While not a one-liner, it should be a fairly short class implementation with two overloaded methods.

Two things of note: You first need to get the syntax tree from the `IMethodSymbol` via its `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` to be able to visit the syntax tree. You can obtain the various symbols from expressions by first getting a `SemanticModel` for that syntax tree from the `Compilation` and query it for the respective symbol.